# Derivative of a conjugate in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, derivative, differentiation

When I try to differentiate a symbol with SymPy I get the following

```
In : x=Symbol('x')
In : diff(x,x)
Out: 1
```

When I differentiate the symbol respect to its conjugate the result is

```
In [55]: diff(x,x.conjugate())
Out[55]: 0
```

However, when I try to differentiate the conjugate of the symbol SymPy doesn't do it

```
In : diff(x.conjugate(),x)
Out: Derivative(conjugate(x), x)
```

This is still correct, but the result should be zero. How can I make SimPy perform the derivative of a conjugate?

Comment: I'm not sure that the derivative of conjugate should be zero.

Comment: That's how we've always done it in class. The derivative of the conjugate is zero unless the variable is real, in that case it is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the mathematics if `diff(conjugate(x), x)` should be zero. The fact that `diff(x,x.conjugate())` gives zero has nothing to do with mathematics (and might even be considered a SymPy bug). It gives zero simply because `x` does not contain `conjugate(x)` (symbolically), so it sees it as a constant with respect to it. This is probably wrong, since `x` is not a constant with respect to `conjugate(x)`. The fact that SymPy lets you take derivatives with respect to defined functions is probably a bug, actually. It is supposed to allow things like `diff(f(x)**2, f(x))`, where `f = Function('f')` is an undefined function, but for defined functions, it is probably mathematically incorrect (or at least not what you expect).

See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=derivative#sympy.core.function.Derivative, particularly the section on derivatives wrt non-Symbols. To paraphrase, taking derivatives with respect to a function is *just a notational convenience* and *does not represent a mathematical chain rule*. Rather, something like `diff(x, conjugate(x))` should be thought of as something like `diff(x.subs(conjugate(x), dummy), dummy).subs(dummy, conjugate(x))`.

Regarding `conjugate(x).diff(x)`, this gives an unevaluated derivative because no derivative is defined for conjugate. I'm not sure if any closed-form answer is possible here anyway. Probably this is the most useful thing that SymPy could return. I can't find any good answers anywhere as to what a reasonable answer for this should be (you should ask on math SE to get a better answer about it).

Comment: I have opened https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3928 relating to this.