# What exactly is the `subs` argument of the `evalf` method of SymPy Expression for? Like `s.evalf(subs={...})`?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I stumbled on this as it did not behave as I expected it to. What exactly is `s.evalf(subs={t: 0})` for?

It seems to be neither a "shortcut" for `s.evalf().subs({t: 0})` nor for `s.evalf().subs({t: 0})` as

```
import sympy

omega, t = sympy.symbols("omega, t")
s = sympy.pi * sympy.cos(omega*t)

# both result in 3.14159265358979
print(s.evalf().subs({t: 0}))
print(s.subs({t: 0}).evalf())
# results in 3.14159265358979*cos(omega*t)
print(s.evalf(subs={t: 0}))
```

results in

```
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979*cos(omega*t)
```

Couldn't find good documentation on this. Maybe someone knows the answer? Otherwise I might have to take a look at the source code to find out more...

Comment: The two different things you're comparing it to seem to be identical.

Comment: *Substitute* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evalf(subs=...)` tries to avoid loss of significance that can happen from naive substitution.

For example

```
>>> (x + y - z).subs({x: 1e100, y: 1, z: 1e100})
0
>>> (x + y - z).evalf(subs={x: 1e100, y: 1, z: 1e100})
1.00000000000000
```

Naive substitution evaluates `1e100 + 1 - 1e100`, which loses the `1` because the default precision, 15 digits, is not enough to keep that information. With `evalf(subs=...)` the expression is run through the evalf algorithm, which is careful about issues like this where significance can be lost. The `subs` dictionary tells the evalf algorithms which symbols should be replaced with numbers when they are encountered. You can see [the source of evalf.py](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/evalf.py) if you are interested in the nitty-gritty details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I'm very sorry, I still fail to see where precision would be the reason why my example above won't work with `evalf(subs=...)` as well. Why isn't `t` replaced at all?

Comment: @Jayjayyy ah I did not notice that. That is a [known bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6974) in SymPy. `evalf(subs=...)` currently does not work unless you replace every Symbol in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/core/evalf.html#N) just says:

> See also the docstring of .evalf() for information on the options.

You can do `help(sympy.evalf)` in an interactive session, or you can click [source](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/core/evalf.html#N) on `N` and scroll up a bit to the docstring. Either way:

> ```
>    subs=<dict>
>        Substitute numerical values for symbols, e.g.
>        subs={x:3, y:1+pi}. The substitutions must be given as a
>        dictionary.
> ```

If you look at [the source for `evalf` itself](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/core/evalf.html#evalf), what this ultimately does is:

```
x = x.subs(evalf_subs(prec, options['subs']))
```

What `evalf_subs` does is:

```
def evalf_subs(prec, subs):
    """ Change all Float entries in `subs` to have precision prec. """
    newsubs = {}
    for a, b in subs.items():
        b = S(b)
        if b.is_Float:
            b = b._eval_evalf(prec)
        newsubs[a] = b
    return newsubs
```

So, a you can see, it's not quite the same as just calling `subs` before calling `eval`. (And of course both of them are quite different from calling `subs` *after* `eval`, even though in some simple examples they end up doing the same thing.)

The intention seems to be that `subs=` can apply the other `evalf` options while the substitution is happening. That "other `evalf` options" appears, from the source, to only be `prec` at present, but presumably that could conceivably change in the future.

At any rate, applying the `prec` to all of the substitutions is a good idea if you're trying to do a numerical approximation with a given precision.

But it might be a bad idea if you're trying to stay with symbolic computation. And I suspect that may be what you're seeing here, although this part is just a guess. Of course `cos(omega*0)` is going to be 1 no matter what `t` is. But `cos(omega*t)` where `t` is within one ulp of 0 at some specific precision is probably 1 plus or minus a few ulps depending on the value of `omega`. So, it can't be reduced.

Comment: Well, okay, so there is `evalf_subs` in between. But I seem to be slow to understand how that makes my example above not work any more. Additionally or alternatively, when would I use the `subs` argument and when call the `subs` method before `evalf`?

Comment: @Jayjayyy Also, more generally—you may not have a use for everything you discover in SymPy. If `subs(…).evalf(…)` is always what you want, you can just use that. (Doing `evalf(…).subs(…)`, on the other hand, could be very different from either; it's more likely that you'll need both for different purposes, even though in this specific example it's identical.)

Comment: @Jayjayyy After looking into things a bit more, I can see how running through `evalf_subs` _could_ make a difference (see updated answer), but I still can't prove that this is why it _does_ make a difference here. Someone would probably need to debug (or grub through the source) a lot deeper to be sure. Is this sufficient, or do you need more?

Comment: This answer isn't accurate. The `subs(evalf_subs(...))` code that you see there is only a fallback. Under ordinary operation, the substitution dictionary is passed through to the evalf routines, which evaluates the expression to the given precision (avoiding loss of significance), substituting the variables as it goes ([here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/125e8863c84473636ddc94500abbd667c291961a/sympy/core/evalf.py#L1225)). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is similar to `Mathematica`'s [`Replace` method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17495317/8033585) to a similar question may be helpful.

Fundamentally, it replaces **symbol** `t` with a value `0`. In your example, this is not very important:

```
print(s.evalf().subs({t: 0}))
print(s.subs({t: 0}).evalf())
```

Both statement result in the same final value. However, when computing, e.g., derivatives, the order matters. For example,

```
In [76]: x=sympy.Symbol('x')

In [77]: sympy.diff(x**2, x)
Out[77]: 2*x

In [78]: sympy.diff((x**2).subs({'x':5}), x)
Out[78]: 0

In [79]: sympy.diff(x**2, x).subs({'x':5})
Out[79]: 10
```

In the first example `x` is replaced with 5 *before* differentiation (and the derivative of 25 with regard to x is 0) and in the second example the derivative is computed first (`2*x`) and then in this derivative expression symbol `x` is replaced with 5 so that the answer is `2*5=10`.

---

EDIT after @abarnet comment:

```
In [85]: import sympy
    ...: 
    ...: omega, t = sympy.symbols("omega, t")
    ...: s = sympy.pi * sympy.cos(omega*t)
    ...: 
    ...: # both result in 3.14159265358979
    ...: print(s.evalf().subs({t: 0}))
    ...: print(s.subs({t: 0}).evalf())
    ...: # results in 3.14159265358979*cos(omega*t)
    ...: print(s.evalf(subs={t: 0, omega: 1}))
    ...: 
    ...: 
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
3.14159265358979
```

So, providing *just* `t` is not enough for `sympy` - it cannot evaluate what is `omega*0` without knowing what `omega` is.

---

EDIT 2:

The second example works because evaluation is performed *after* substitution while the third example is attempting to perform *numerical evaluation* **with given substitutions** and it fails to evaluate the expression numerically (without `omega`) and therefore it leaves the expression in symbolic form. The first example also works because it simply substitutes `t` with 0 and simplifies the expression. However,

```
In [86]: s.evalf()
Out[86]: 3.14159265358979*cos(omega*t)
```

---

EDIT 3:

Investigating the code, it is clear that `evalf` code (actually one of the `evalf_*` functions) attempts to evaluate [**each argument in `args`**](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#args) ***independently*** with given options (i.e., `subs`) before proceeding with evaluation of the expression. So, in the first case, `s.evalf().subs({t: 0})`, the first `eval()` does not do anything (well, almost... - it evaluates `pi` to `3.1415...`) and `subs({t: 0})` replaces `t` with 0 and then the expression is re-evaluated/simplified to `3.14...`. In the second case the substitution is performed first and then `pi` is evaluated as `3.1415...`. In the third case each argument in `s.args` is evaluated. The code fails here (because it cannot evaluate `omega` given provided `subs` option) and returns the input expression unchanged.

That is, the third option `s.eval(subs={t: 0})` **requires** all arguments of `s` to be defined. The check of this is performed [here for the `mul` function](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/125e8863c84473636ddc94500abbd667c291961a/sympy/core/evalf.py#L559) (obviously `sympy` master is ahead of my installed version).

To see this, try a simple expression:

```
In [1]: import sympy
    ...: from sympy.core import evalf
    ...: t, x = sympy.symbols("t, x")
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [2]: (t*x).evalf(subs={t:0})
Out[2]: t*x

In [3]: evalf.evalf(t*x, 10, {t: 0})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/evalf.py in evalf(x, prec, options)
    1285         rf = evalf_table[x.func]
-> 1286         r = rf(x, prec, options)
    1287     except KeyError:

~/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/evalf.py in evalf_symbol(x, prec, options)
    1203 def evalf_symbol(x, prec, options):
-> 1204     val = options['subs'][x]
    1205     if isinstance(val, mpf):

KeyError: 'subs'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/evalf.py in evalf(x, prec, options)
    1292             xe = x._eval_evalf(prec)
-> 1293             re, im = xe.as_real_imag()
    1294             if re.has(re_) or im.has(im_):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'as_real_imag'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e075388b139d> in <module>()
----> 1 evalf.evalf(t*x, 10, {t: 0})

~/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/evalf.py in evalf(x, prec, options)
    1284     try:
    1285         rf = evalf_table[x.func]
-> 1286         r = rf(x, prec, options)
    1287     except KeyError:
    1288         try:

~/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/evalf.py in evalf_mul(v, prec, options)
    536     from sympy.core.numbers import Float
    537     for arg in args:
--> 538         arg = evalf(arg, prec, options)
    539         if arg[0] is None:
    540             continue

~/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/core/evalf.py in evalf(x, prec, options)
    1308             r = re, im, reprec, imprec
    1309         except AttributeError:
-> 1310             raise NotImplementedError
    1311     if options.get("verbose"):
    1312         print("### input", x)

NotImplementedError: 

In [4]:
```

Comment: This is all true about the difference between `subs(…).evalf(…)` and `evalf(…).subs(…)`, but I think the OP already understands that part, and is just trying to figure out which of the two `evalf(…, subs=…)` is like, and how it differs from whichever that is.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks! I did not read the question carefully. I am editing the answer.

Comment: Yes, providing both `t` and `omega` will give you the same result with all three. But that still doesn't explain the problem. After all, the second example _is_ able to evaluate what `omega*0` is (or what `cos(omega*0)` is) without knowing `omega`, but the third one isn't. And nothing in your answer even hints at what the reasons for that might be. It's all valuable background, but I think it's all background the OP probably already has. The only question is whether other people might have a similar question but _not_ have that background, in which case it's probably valuable for that purpose.

Comment: @abarnert I disagree with you. The second example works because evaluation is performed _after_ substitution while the third example is attempting to perform _numerical evaluation_ **with given substitutions** and it fails to evaluate the expression numerically (without `omega`) and therefore it leaves the expression in symbolic form.

Comment: But there is still a call to the `subs` method from inside `evalf` if the `subs` argument is given... Why does that not substitute `t` with `0` and therefore `cos(...)` with `1` before the numerical evaluation?

Comment: @Jayjayyy I edited my answer again with updated info. In any case, it seems that when you use `eval(subs={})` you are required to provide all substitutions to evaluate all arguments before evaluation can proceed. This is different from the case of `s.subs().eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `s.evalf(subs={t: 0})` as a way of saying "evaluate s at the value of t = 0". The evalf machinery tries to give you an answer to the desired precision while taking care of intermediate precision during the calculation. (Aaron has already given a good example where evaluation of a sum will give an incorrect answer if the values are simply substituted in and evaluated in the order dictated by Python.)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a workaround for this problem as well. The following seems to do the trick in case of [asmeurer's code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459066/1185254):

```
from sympy import symbols, Float
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')

(x + y - z).subs({x: Float(1e100, 100), y: 1, z: Float(1e100, 100)})
```

which properly evaluates to 1.0.